# Non-significant Multiple Regression Coefficients to significant journey

Tags: regression

I am teaching my students Multiple linear regression.I loaded a dataset and fit multiple regression to it using SPSS.
I got non-significant regression coefficients with some negative and positive values.
Now a student asked me how can one manipulate the variable(s) corresponding to the specific non significant regression coefficient so that we have significant result?

**My Intuition**

Significant regression coefficient means that by changing value of that variable and keeping the rest constant it show it has significant effect on the output variable.But I do not know how that variable manipulation can change significance of the corresponding regression coefficient?

Comment: You're asking how to do significance-hunting (data dredging)?

Comment: @Glen_b  yes please tell me if you have any suggestion here....do u have some magic say as to how to manipulate those variables so to get significant regression coefficients?................

Answer (score 1):

You can divide the explanatory variable by its non-significant coefficient to get a perfect fit.